# Is a ticket, in addition to Gadearmbånd, recommended for Copenhagen Distortion music festival?

Tags: denmark, copenhagen, festivals

For the [Copenhagen Distortion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copenhagen_Distortion) music festival, on [cphdistortion.dk](https://www.cphdistortion.dk) they list various tickets. It looks like the only I need to get is Gadearmbånd.

Quote from [visitcopenhagen:](https://www.visitcopenhagen.com/copenhagen/distortion-gdk759015)

> The legendary street raves are financed by the thousands of guests who
>   buy the “Gadearmbånd” so Distortion can clean up the streets when the
>   incomparable music and street rave labyrinth ends. Distortion Ø and
>   Distortion Club are ticketed events and the Distortion Pass will get
>   you access to all the music-mayhem.

Can anybody tell me what I will get with Distortion Ø? Do most people buy it? What is the benefit? Can I also buy local when I am there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the 2017 program, having an armband will get you access to things like "luxury toilets" (LUKSUSTOILETTER), the Royal Distortion main stage, and free beer from 16:00 - 18:00 at Country House (RÅDHUSPLADSEN). I can't tell if it will get you into the street parties or not.

Here's a link to the [2017 program](http://nusnus.dk/2017/distortion-2017-program.pdf) (PDF).

There's a statement in the program, that you have to trade your online ticket/receipt for a wristband on-site and that you cannot buy tickets at those locations.

If you look at the last page of the program, it says that the arm band gets "street benefits" (so do the other tickets).